# "Invoking" Powershell workflow from a script

Tags: powershell, powershell-workflow

I am pretty new to Powershell and Powershell Workflows. In all the Workflow examples I've seen on the internet, the workflow is "defined" and "invoked" from the same file, like below:

```
workflow test-workflow {
    $random = 1
    $random
}

test-workflow
```

This is a pretty lame example where the workflow simply prints the value "1". What I want to do is define the workflow in a file called say "test-workflow.ps1" and invoke it from another Powershell script file called say "test-script.ps1". Is that possible?

Comment: Look into dot-sourcing. Personally I just use functions instead of workflows.

Comment: Yup, dot sourcing was the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dot-source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847841.aspx) the script with the workflow implementation in your other script:

```psh
. C:\path\to\workflow.ps1

Test-Workflow
```